# What is the state of the dart debugger?

Tags: dart

I am having hard times debugging my code with the **Dart Editor version 0.5.0_r21823** on Mac OS X.

It stops with following info:

"Dart_InstanceGetClass expects argument 'instance' to be of type Instance."

I am now trying the poor man's debugger (i.e. print ...) but even that one fails.

```dart
_setupGui() {
  // Bitmap background = new Bitmap(resourceManager.getBitmapData("Pigeon"));
  print("Done loading resources");
  ChessBoard b = new ChessBoard();
  board = new ChessBoardView(b);
  stage.addChild(board);
  ....

/**
 * Holds a chess position.
 */
class ChessBoard {

  static const String STARTPOS = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";

  ChessBoard([String fen = STARTPOS]) {
     print("ChessBoard($fen)");     // This gets written
     _setFromFen(fen);
  }

  void _setFromFen(String fen) {
    print("_setFromFEN($fen)");   // This is not written
    ...
```

Console output:

```
Fixed Canvas Style Size !!!!
Loading resources
Done loading resources
ChessBoard(rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1)
... here it ends. I.e. setFromFEN() is not written ...
```

Comment: Can you narrow this: > "Dart_InstanceGetClass expects argument 'instance' to be of type Instance." down to a test case, and submit it as a bug at [dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com/new)? A small, reproducable test case makes it much easier for us to find and fix bugs. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to to that next time I encounter this! Right now the problem is gone and as I recall it had to do with errors in constructor/factory methods.

Comment: Now I have this same problem. The debugger fails to stop on breakpoints with this message. I will try to reproduce (with minimal example) when I got time over ...

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug, which has likely been fixed by now. If you're using Dartium; you can use the built-in dev tools to debug (much like you would with JavaScript) which can be very convenient!